# Ripping out the hidden kernel module by reading kernel memory directly?

Tags: linux, kernel

Is it possible to find hidden kernel modules by reading kernel memory directly?

By hiding I mean a LKM that removes itself from the kernel module list.

If so, what structure should I expect, or what document should I read?

Comment: Interesting. Just of curiosity, what are such modules actually used for? Rootkits or the like, perhaps? Do they ever get unloaded and are they meant to be?

Comment: @Eugene You can never unload them as their names are removed from the list, rootkits, indeed.

Comment: If a module has removed itself from the list of modules, what is left are two memory areas in the module mapping space where the code and the data of the module are stored, "init" (everything marked with `__init` and `__init_data` goes here) and "core" (other code and data sections). On x86, you can see the implementation of [module_alloc()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/module.c) to understand how memory is allocated for a module there. Each of these two memory areas is continuous (the module loader allocates them this way).

Comment: (continued) In theory, you could enumerate the modules left in the module list to see which memory areas they occupy. Then - scan the module mapping space for something looking like code that does not belong to these areas. Don't know if this is actually possible but this could be a starting point to dig in further.

Comment: Another thing that could be helpful against "not-so-clever" rootkits. If the module has only removed itself from the module list, information about it may still be left in sysfs, see `/sys/module/*`. It is not that easy for a module to delete/hide it, so if you see a subdirectory there with a name absent from the list of modules (and different from "kernel" and other special names of course) this could be it. A clever rootkit could try to hide that data as well. I myself would like to see an example of it because I currently know no way to.

Comment: Something like this could be used to check sysfs: `for mm in /sys/module/*; do if test -d ${mm}/sections; then MOD="$(basename ${mm})"; lsmod | grep -E "^${MOD}" > /dev/null || printf "${MOD}\n"; fi; done`

Comment: @Eugene cool, I'm taking a look at the source code now...

Answer (score 1):

following @Eugene, I find a way to read kernel memory directly to find the so called not-so-clever hidden module: just compare the module from both procfs perspective and sysfs perspective:

```
static int detect_hidden_mod_init(void)
{
    char *procfs_modules[MAX_MODULE_SIZE];
    char *sysfs_modules[MAX_MODULE_SIZE];
    int proc_module_index = 0, sys_module_index = 0;

    struct module *mod;
    struct list_head *p;

    // get modules from procfs perspective
    list_for_each(p, &__this_module.list){
        mod = list_entry(p, struct module, list);
        procfs_modules[proc_module_index++] = mod->name;
    }


    // get modules from sysfs perspective
    struct kobject *kobj;
    struct kset *kset = __this_module.mkobj.kobj.kset;
    list_for_each(p, &kset->list) {
        kobj = container_of(p, struct kobject, entry);
        sysfs_modules[sys_module_index++] = kobj->k_name;
    }

    //compare the procfs_modules and sysfs_modules
    ...
}
```

Actually it can detect most of current module-hidden rootkit, however as Eugene said, "A clever rootkit could try to hide that data as well". So it is not a perfect way.